# Remove wp-caption but still show the image

Tags: captions

I have been using wp-caption for so long but for a template I am working on I want to delete this tag and only show the image, 
I used display:none; function but it does not show the image ,
any help ?

Comment: `.wp-caption-text{display: none;}`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the img_caption_shortcode filter to do this. Pretty certain the alignment of the image (floating left/right) is part of the caption so you'll lose the ability to do that with this code.

```
function imageOnly($deprecated, $attr, $content = null) 
{
    return do_shortcode( $content );
}
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'imageOnly', 10, 3 );
```

The do_shortcode is probably overkill.

I use something very similar to change the caption output to be responsive. Tested on WordPress 3.8.1

Comment: `do_shortcode()` is helpful, if you like it, that the shortcodes inside the content works after remove caption --> +1 for this answer.

Comment: Didn't worked for me in WP 4.2.5

Answer (score 0):

This code found on the WP Support forums ([Can you remove captions from images?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-you-remove-captions-from-images)) worked for me:

```
function no_caption($deprecated, $attr, $content) { return $content; };
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', 'no_caption', 10, 3);
```

Just drop it in your theme's functions.php

Comment: Didn't worked for me in WP 4.2.5